# Rails -Sort list based on the string name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to show the list of builds as follows

```
AppName     bundle
ABCD        test_1.3.5.0_AdHoc.ipa
ABCD        test_1.3.5.0_Store.ipa
DAA         test_1.3.4.0_AdHoc.ipa
DAA         test_1.3.4.0_Store.ipa
```

For the app ABCD, I should show "AdHoc.ipa" first, then "Store.ipa"

**Builds table**

```
id:integer appname:string bundle:string created_at:datetime
```

**Build table data**

```
+-----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | app_name | bundle                                                                           |
+-----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  36 |          ABCD | test_1.3.5.0_AdHoc.ipa                         |
|  37 |          DAA | test_AdHoc_.ipa                            |
|  38 |          ABCD | test_1.3.5.0_Store.ipa                         |
|  39 |          DAA | test_1.3.5.0_Store.ipa                         |
```

How should i achieve this ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.order` and pass the 2 columns in the order that you want.
First `app_name` and then `bundle`.

```
Build.all.order('app_name ASC, bundle ASC')
```